# How do I know where homebrew installs symlinks?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Where does homebrew create symlinks? I know that it appears to be `$(brew --prefix)/bin`, but where is this documented? Can things be linked elsewhere?

When I run `brew install node`, I end up with `node` on my path at `/usr/local/bin/node`:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

`brew unlink` and `brew link` will remove them and add them back for me. According to `man brew`, `brew link` will symlink "all of formula's installed files into the Homebrew prefix". However:

```
$ brew --prefix
/usr/local
```

It seems like the correct statement would be "into the Homebrew prefix + bin". Can formula sometimes link to places other than `$(brew --prefix)/bin`? Is the +bin idea formula-dependent? Should it actually say something like "into the Homebrew prefix plus a formula-specific suffix (usually bin)"? I've looked at a few formulae and it doesn't seem to be, although I could be missing it.

I'm trying to gain a more complete understanding of Homebrew, and this has long confused me. I'm not having any problems, I'm just trying to figure out if the documentation is incomplete, if there is a command I'm missing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, symlinks can be placed elsewhere. For example, a formula might put a symlink at `$(brew --prefix)/lib`. You can list all of a formula's files by running `brew ls $formula` (although not all files are necessarily symlinked into a subdirectory of `brew --prefix`, but most are).

Comment: `brew ls $formula` looks very promising! Is there a way to see where the links themselves will be (or have been) created? For example, it looks as if `brew ls node` shows me all the files that have been linked (man pages, bash completion for npm, the node binary, etc). I'd like to see where they will be or have been linked. Is that possible?

Comment: @user1978019: You can run `brew link` with the `--dry-run` flag.

Comment: ah right, that works for the "will link" case. It fails for an already linked package, but I suppose `brew unlink node && brew link --dry-run node` would get the job done. This is still a bit confusing, as it shows the links and the files but I have to pair them up myself as to which link will go to which file. Not as friendly as the `->` syntax I prefer, but still doable. Also odd, `brew link node` says it creates 6 symlinks, `brew link --dry-run node` shows 6 symlinks, but `brew unlink` says it removes 7 symlinks... Hmm.